# JavaFX reading a text file and displaying it to multiple text fields

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I have a text file with 4 lines of random words, line for line, and I need to be able to read each line and display it to its text field (First line goes into first text field, etc), but it is only reading the last line and displaying it into any text field.

"myfile.txt"
one

two

three

onetwothree

```
TextField label1Text = new TextField();
TextField label2Text = new TextField();
TextField label3Text = new TextField();


load.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent l) {
        
        
        String line = ""; 
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
              
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           
              label1Text.setText(line);
              label2Text.setText(line);
              label3Text.setText(line);
              labelO2Text.setText(line);   
            }
            
        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
    }
    
    });

    primaryStage.show();
    

    
}
```

}

Comment: "For each line in the file, display the line in all four text fields." It's doing exactly what you ask it to do.

Comment: Try it without the loop.

Comment: Your while loop finishes and on that last go around, all fields get populated with the last line.  Try putting your textfields in an array and populate each line by index.

Comment: this is unrelated to fx, it's plain java. So time to work through a tutorial on language basics, in particular on what loops are  ..

Answer (score 1):

Your current code reads each line in turn, and for each line sets the text of all the labels to that line of text.

Instead, you need to take each label in turn, and set its text to the next line from the file. You can do that with something like:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"))) {
    List.of(label1Text, label2Text, label3Text, label02Text)
        .forEach(label -> {
             try {
                label.setText(reader.readLine());
             } catch (IOException exc) {
                 // handle exception
             }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a single line, then setting the content of that line to all 3/4 TextFields (there is one missing in your example). After the loop finishes, all TextFields are set to the content of the last line of your file.

There is a variety of ways to achieve what you want - if you only ever have 4 entries, the following will work:

```
 String[] lines = new String[4];
 int index = 0;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
    lines[index++] = line;
    if (index==4) break;
 }
 label1Text.setText(lines[0]);
 label2Text.setText(lines[1]);
 label3Text.setText(lines[2]);
 label4Text.setText(lines[3]);
```

If you had references to your TextFields in an array, you could also do

```
 int index = 0;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
    labels[index++].setText(line);
    if (index==4) break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem sits in your loop

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    label1Text.setText(line);
    label2Text.setText(line);
    label3Text.setText(line);
    labelO2Text.setText(line);   
}
```

Basically if we look at the loop, first iteration changes all of the labels to the word "One", second iteration in the loop sets all the labels to "Two", than "Three" and last iteration sets all labels as "Four".

To solve the problem you can add a simple counter with some if statements, so it will tell your loop what to do.

```
int counter = 0;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(counter == 0)
        label1Text.setText(line);
    if(counter == 1)
        label2Text.setText(line);
    if(counter == 2)
        label3Text.setText(line);
    if(counter == 3)
        labelO2Text.setText(line);
    counter++;                      
}
```

I am sure it is not the most optimal way, but if you want to do it with loop, that's it.